# How can i refresh listview in android?

Tags: android

This is my code :
Here _alProduct is an ArrayList defined static in the main class.
I am deleting an item from _alProduct on long click of listview.
Now I want to display the listview with the deleted item removed.

public class MCRActivity2 extends Activity {

```
TextView tvShoppingCart;
ListView lvSelectedItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mcractivity2);

    lvSelectedItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSelectedItems);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobileCashRegisterActivity._alProduct);

    lvSelectedItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvSelectedItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            String text = "Clicked item is " + adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//    ""+ lvSelectedItems.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            MobileCashRegisterActivity._alProduct.remove(position);
            MobileCashRegisterActivity._alPrice.remove(position);
            MobileCashRegisterActivity._alQuantity.remove(position);

            return false;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `remove()` on your `ArrayAdapter`, instead of calling `remove()` on the `ArrayList`. This will both remove the item from the `ArrayList` and tell the `AdapterView` to refresh its contents.

Comment: can you PLEASE write some code Sir, how to do it because it is showing functions like removeAllViews() etc

Comment: I can't found apapter.remove() funtion